# Is Time scheduling problem np hard or np complete?

Tags: linear-programming, np-complete

I have a set of courses and each courses have a set of classes. Each classes have a set of timings available with some penalty. I wanted to schedule each classes to any of the timings of its with a minimum value of penalty and minimum violation pf soft constraints (because each soft constraints violation gives some penalty).
I am not sure whether this problem is np hard or np complete.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: It would probably be useful to you to read the answers to this [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard) as well.

Answer (score 0):

NP-complete problems are [decision problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem) by definition.  NP-hard problems include decision problems but also encompass search and optimization problems like yours.

Comment: I have searched for a lot of papers regarding class scheduling and curriculum based scheduling, but I was not able to find any paper that proved these type of problems are np hard. Whereas,  this paper says [link](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.959.421&rep=rep1&type=pdf)  the problem is np complete. This is making me more confused.

Comment: An NP-hard problem can sometimes be posed in such a way that the new question is NP-complete.  For example, if the Travelling Salesman problem is posed as "is there a route with a cost < $k$?", then that problem is NP-complete, since the question is NP-hard and any "yes" answer has a certificate verifiable in polynomial-time.  Pose the problem as "find the minimal cost route that visits all the cities", then that problem is not yes-no answerable and a solution is not polynomial-time verifiable.  Can you see how to do the same sort of reframing of your problem to go from NP-hard to NP-complete?